# Vim highlighting with solarized color scheme

Tags: vim, color-scheme

I have a vim highlight to display whitespace errors in code:

```
" Highlight redundant whitespaces and tabs.
highlight RedundantSpaces ctermbg=red
match RedundantSpaces /\s\+$\| \+\ze\t\|\t/
```

Which displays trailing whitespace problems like this:
[image: White space errors highlighted in red]

However, i've recently started using the [solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) color scheme and I am not able to get these highlights to display.
[image: solarized with no highlights]

I've tried changing the color names to no avail.  The relevant part of my (simple) .vimrc says:

```
syntax enable
set background=dark
colorscheme solarized
```

Comment: Where are you calling the highlight?

Comment: In my .vimrc? (not sure if I understand the question)

Comment: Before or after you call `colorscheme solarized`?

Comment: Before, I think thats it..thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Moving the `:highlight` after the `:colorscheme` still doesn't help you when you switch colorschemes in the Vim session.

For that to work, re-define your highlighting via the `ColorScheme` event:

```
autocmd ColorScheme * highlight RedundantSpaces ctermbg=red
```

---

BTW, your minimalistic solution has other problems:

1. It does not highlight in split windows.
2. You lose the ability of quickly highlighting custom stuff via `:match`.

There are several plugins that offer this functionality, in a better way. Mine is called [ShowTrailingWhitespace](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3966); the plugin page contains links to alternatives.